# import wab (outlook express address book) into Oultook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, import, address-book, outlook-express

How can I import all my contacts from that file?
I do not have XP with outlook express anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to any XP computer you'll have to resort to some commercial software (e.g. [Address Magic Personal](http://www.connectedsw.com/Overview/57262), $29.95).

Cheaper but more time consuming would be setting up a virtual xp machine (e.g. with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)), import the address book and then export to CSV.

*Of course there are plenty other useful scenarios where a VM comes in handy, for instance, a 'disposable' virtual computer will add greatly to your security.*

If you don't have XP or a spare license, you can grab a free **[Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)** (any of the 3 XP versions will do) and use it for with **[Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)**.

### Update

If you want to import your mails, read this tutorial:

**[Import your messages or account from Outlook Express to Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA010943871033.aspx)**

expand the link **When Outlook and Outlook Express are installed on different computers**

Comment: and what about by inbox folder, can i import it?

Comment: @matiki - updated my post.